# AlreadyBuiltException while configuring multiple HttpSecurity instances with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring v.5.3.28 and Spring Security v.5.8.4, and I'm trying to configure Spring Security without extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as it has been deprecated.

My Spring Security configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String SIGNIN = "/signin";

    @Autowired
    ApiCustomAuthenticationProviderImpl apiCustomAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    LdapAuthenticationProviderImpl ldapAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    SautenticaAuthenticationProviderImpl sautenticaAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService () {
        return new AutenticacionServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension () {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<Usuario> auditorAware () {
        return new SpringSecurityAuditorAware();
    }

    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);

        final String authMode = configurationService.findByCode(Constants.CT_AUTH_MODE);

        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(authMode) && Constants.CT_LDAP.equalsIgnoreCase(authMode)) {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);
        } else if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(authMode) && Constants.CT_SAUTENTICA.equalsIgnoreCase(authMode)) {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(sautenticaAuthenticationProvider);
        } else {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }

        authenticationManagerBuilder.eraseCredentials(false);

        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        try {
            http.securityMatcher("/api-ws/**");
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
            http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api-ws/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable()
                    .addFilterAfter(new ApiCustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.authenticationProvider(apiCustomAuthenticationProvider);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain wsSecurityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        try {
            http.securityMatcher("/ws/**");
            http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/ws/patient/**", "/meet-ws/case/**").authenticated();
            http.httpBasic().and().addFilterAt(new CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter(getAuthenticationManager(http)), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer () {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/ws/login**", "/ws/new/xml**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        try {
            http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/health**", "/signin**", "/authenticate**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().authenticationManager(getAuthenticationManager(http)).formLogin().loginPage(SIGNIN).permitAll().loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").permitAll()
                    .failureUrl("/signin?error=1").successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and().sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl(SIGNIN).and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler()).and().headers().frameOptions().disable();

            http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl(SIGNIN).permitAll();
        
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

When I build the project it builds successfully but when I start the server it throws the following exception:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityFilterChain' defined in es.mycompany.myapp.SecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'wsSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wsSecurityFilterChain' defined in es.mycompany.myapp.SecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'wsSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1462)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'wsSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException: This object has already been built
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.beforeConfigure(HttpSecurity.java:3225)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:308)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38)
    at es.mycompany.myapp.SecurityConfiguration.wsSecurityFilterChain(SecurityConfiguration.java:152)
    at es.mycompany.myapp.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aaa83f30.CGLIB$wsSecurityFilterChain$7(<generated>)
    at es.mycompany.myapp.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aaa83f30$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed15352b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at es.mycompany.myapp.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aaa83f30.wsSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 63 more
```

The only thing that I can think of is http.build(); being called twice, but they do the exact same thing in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_multiple_httpsecurity_instances

Answer (score 1):

The error you receive comes from calling `authenticationManagerBuilder.build()` yourself. You are accessing an internal framework instance of the builder and calling `build()` yourself, while Spring Security also builds the authentication manager internally.

Generally, any `AuthenticationProvider` that is a `@Bean` (or `@Component`, etc.) will be autowired by Spring Security. You will want to restructure your application so you can conditionally apply the desired `AuthenticationProvider` to the relevant filter chain (instead of publishing as beans). The entire `getAuthenticationManager` method should be removed.